# Create an array from HTML in a specific form with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, arrays

I'm having problems with the following piece. I'm trying to create some gallery of my own, but I'm in the very early beginning of learning jQuery, and all this array stuff is pretty hard for me to understand..

In my CMS I have created a looped output in the following form for all elements:

```
<img class="content" src="path/to/image1.jpg" />
<p class="title">Description1</p>
<a class="link_img" href="http://www.somesite1.com" target="_blank">Link to Site1</a>

<img class="content" src="path/to/image2.jpg" />
<p class="title">Description2</p>
<a class="link_img" href="http://www.somesite2.com" target="_blank">Link to Site2</a>
```

But I need to bring it into this form (for my jQuery playground):

```
var myDemoImages = [
    { src: 'path/to/image1.jpg', title: 'Description1', subtitle: 'http://www.somesite1.com' },
    { src: 'path/to/image2.jpg', title: 'Description2', subtitle: 'http://www.somesite2.com' }
];
```

I tried something like the following, but it's mixing up values, doubling values.

```
$('img.content').each(function() {
    for (var k = 0; k < this.attributes.length; k++)
    {
        var attr = this.attributes[k];
        if (attr.name != 'class')
            myImages.push("src:'"+attr.value+"'");
    }
});
```

Also the "value" I need from the `p` tag is actually not a value, but shouldn't something like this work?

```
myImages.push(this.innerHTML);
```

Comment: you have a variable named " myDemoImages" but no  "myImages" variable (you used for pushin the src. are they identical?

Answer (score 2):

I would do something like:

```
<div class="demoImage">
<img class="content" src="path/to/image1.jpg" /> 
<p class="title">Description1</p>
<a class="link_img" href="http://www.somesite1.com" target="_blank">Link to Site1</a>
</div>
```

Note that I added a `div` around your elements to make it easier to access them.

And the jQuery:

```
var fos=$('.demoImage').map(function () {
    var $this=$(this);
    return {
        src: $this.find('img.content').attr('src'),
        title: $this.find('p.title').html(),
        subtitle: $this.find('a.link_img').attr('href'),
    };
}).get();
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hfpVc/)

The solution uses the [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) function which is a great tool to create any arrays out of your jQuery collections.

Comment: Very nice elegant way of doing this. Do you not find it irritating that jQuery does so many things with .get -- it can retrieve X element from the matched set, get the last mapped array (which I didn't even know about since your example), or be an ajax get request. I think it's so fragmented!

Comment: @Gary Green On the contrary, I like it. `get` has a lot of meanings also in the English language, the meaning depends on the context in most cases. Javascript is a programming *language* in the end, so I find this intuitive. I'd hate to write `getLastMappedArray` or `getElement`, etc.

Comment: Obviously it's shorter to write, but `getElement` etc is more descriptive and intuitive to me. It's also a nuisance finding the correct page for `.get` from the API in the context you want to use it.

Comment: @Gary Green Then it's down to personal preference it seems :).

Comment: True, try typing "get" into the search and you'll come up with a page for disamguation. Also you'll see no mention of `.get` for use in `.map` -- it only appears on the `.map` page. Makes you wonder where else `.get` can be ambiguously used.

Comment: @Gary Green I'd argue with that. There is a page for the Ajax `jQuery.get()` and one for [`.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/). The latter explains that without arguments, it will return a simple Javascript array out of the collection (with example and explanation). And `.map()` returns a collection, it seems pretty straightforward to me.

Answer (score 0):

- To get the HTML content from the `p` tag, use the `$("p").html()` method.
- To get inner text, use the `.text()` method :-)